# Passing of double parameters for the jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am making a report that using parameters:
`Start date`, `end date` and `type` (which can be: input, output or input and output).

Everything works fine until I try to get the report that gets input and output

I've tried it in many ways and I can not get results.

Query in report:

[image]

Java:

```
protected void relEntrada(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
try{
    SessionImplementor sim = (SessionImplementor) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Connection con = sim.connection();

    String tipoMov = request.getParameter("tipMov");

    String dataini = request.getParameter("dataini");
    String dtini[] = dataini.split("/");
    String diai = dtini[0];
    String mesi = dtini[1];
    String anoi = dtini[2];

    String datafim = request.getParameter("datafim");
    String dtfim[] = datafim.split("/");
    String diaf = dtfim[0];
    String mesf = dtfim[1];
    String anof = dtfim[2];

    HashMap param = new HashMap();
    param.put("dataini",  anoi +"-"+mesi+"-"+diai + " 00:00:00" );
    param.put("datafim", anof +"-"+mesf+"-"+diaf + " 23:59:59" );

    if (tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("entrada")) {
        param.put("tipmov", "entrada" );
    } else if(tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("saida")) {
        param.put("tipmov", "saida" );
    } else if(tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("entradaesaida")) {
        param.put("tipmov", "entrada or tipo = "+'"'+"saida"+'"');
    }

    InputStream arquivo = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/relatorios/RelMoviment.jasper");

    byte[] pdf = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(arquivo, param ,con);

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
    out.write(pdf);
    out.flush();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I get the results with only the input, the results with the output sum but I can not get the results with input and output ... how would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But one thing I was not calling was in! Of p {} ... there would never go the way I wanted or do a ternary .... after I put p! {} Everything was cool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [dynamic queries](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query) functionality.

1. In your query have:

   ```
   and he.tipo=$P!{tipmov}
   ```

   notice the `$P!` syntax
2. In your Java code have:

   ```
   if (tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("entrada")) {
       param.put("tipmov", "'entrada'" );
   } else if(tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("saida")) {
       param.put("tipmov", "'saida'" );
   } else if(tipoMov.equalsIgnoreCase("entradaesaida")) {
       param.put("tipmov", "'entrada' or he.tipo='saida'");
   }
   ```

   notice the single quote escapes for each parameter value.

Comment: I get the results with only the input, the results with the output sum but I can not get the results with input and output ... how would you do that?

Comment: Maybe you need to wrap the *and* part of the query in parentheses. Try: `and (he.tipo = $P!{tipmov})` and see what happens.